# Node JS Context Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have some code in my controller like following

```
const express = require('express');
const AuthService = require('../../services/auth');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', AuthService.login);
```

Now when i call login method in my services, and call another method from inside login method like.

```
class Authentication {

  login (req, res) {
    this.notify();
    res.send({message: 'login method'});
  }

  notify () {
    console.log('this is just a notification method.');
  }
}

module.exports = new Authentication();
```

I get following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined

I know it's context issue, But i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Isn't it `res.end();` instead of `res.send();`?

Comment: Send also works here. But it's not the real problem.

Comment: var self = this;
self.notify();

try this.

Comment: (TL;DR of the duplicate: replace `AuthService.login` with `AuthService.login.bind(AuthService)`)

Comment: @SameerAhmad It also doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeClay I know binding can solve this issue, but i wanna know if i need to do this for each route?

Comment: just use arrow functions or bind. And yes, you have to do it for every middleware that requires the right context